# Telegram bot aiogram erros

Tags: bots, telegram, aiogram

[mistakes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Tsa.png)

[mistakes 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIkvG.png)
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjjZO.png)

https://github.com/mahenzon/aiogram-lessons/tree/master/lesson-02
I can't understand why my code isn't working. I took code from here and only change file config.py, change token and MY_ID.

executor.py [ LINE:362 ]#    INFO [2021-08-12 14:43:46,938]  Bot: lap156 [@lab156_bot]
dispatcher.py [ LINE:360 ]#    INFO [2021-08-12 14:43:46,938]  Start polling.
base_events.py [ LINE:1738 ]#   ERROR [2021-08-12 14:47:59,585]  Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-24' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=WrongFileIdentifier('Wrong file identifier/http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Zver\aiogram-lessons\lesson-02\bot.py", line 55, in process_photo_command
await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, CAT_BIG_EYES,
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 482, in send_photo
result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_PHOTO, payload, files)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified
base_events.py [ LINE:1738 ]#   ERROR [2021-08-12 14:48:03,624]  Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-32' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=WrongFileIdentifier('Wrong file identifier/http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Zver\aiogram-lessons\lesson-02\bot.py", line 73, in process_note_command
await bot.send_video_note(message.from_user.id, VIDEO_NOTE)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 963, in send_video_note
result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_VIDEO_NOTE, payload, files)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified
base_events.py [ LINE:1738 ]#   ERROR [2021-08-12 14:48:06,943]  Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-37' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=WrongFileIdentifier('Wrong file identifier/http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Zver\aiogram-lessons\lesson-02\bot.py", line 55, in process_photo_command
await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, CAT_BIG_EYES,
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 482, in send_photo
result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_PHOTO, payload, files)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified
base_events.py [ LINE:1738 ]#   ERROR [2021-08-12 14:48:15,298]  Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-41' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=WrongFileIdentifier('Wrong file identifier/http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
File "C:\Users\Zver\aiogram-lessons\lesson-02\bot.py", line 73, in process_note_command
await bot.send_video_note(message.from_user.id, VIDEO_NOTE)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 963, in send_video_note
result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_VIDEO_NOTE, payload, files)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
File "C:\Users\Zver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified

Comment: Hi, please do not post screenshots of the errors copy and paste them here.
From the error it seems that one instance of the bot is already running when you run your code. Terminate all running terminals/processes and try again.

Comment: I think that's not the problem, the code works on /help and /start and on /testpre and outputs what is needed. The bot does not work for the other remaining commands

Comment: @Geom what can you say about "photo" it's third picture

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error it seems that one running terminal of the bot is already running when you run your code. So Terminate all running terminals/processes and try again.

Comment: I think that's not the problem, the code works on /help and /start and on /testpre and outputs what is needed. The bot does not work for the other remaining commands

Comment: I tried it with another new token, it outputs the same thing

Comment: Maybe some errors in code can you paste it and show

Comment: aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified

Comment: Ok gotcha! Can you share me your config.py file

Comment: TOKEN = "1847222580:AAFjorOK3YeXbxJ7Hf7AwwP67hI7pf2Vtgg"
MY_ID = 694477371

DB_FILENAME = 'botuploads.db'